# Export ppt slide in c# provides error: PowerPoint can't save ^0 to ^1.'

Tags: c#, export, powerpoint

I'm trying to save all slides as image to a folder, however on doing so I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred
> Slide (unknown member) : PowerPoint can't save ^0 to ^1.

The code:

```
PowerPoint.Application application = new PowerPoint.Application();
PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = application.Presentations.Open2007(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings sst1 = presentation.SlideShowSettings;

PowerPoint.Slides slides = presentation.Slides;
String folder = @"C:/Users/user/Downloads/folder/";

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);

foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
{
    fi.Delete();
}


foreach (PowerPoint.Slide slide in slides)
{
    String exportName = folder + slide.Name + ".png";
    slide.Export(exportName, "png");
}
```

The slide.Export(exportName, "png"); causes the problem according to visual studio.

I have no idea how this occurs and the folder does exist.
Windows 11

PS. If anybody knows how I can export not into a physical image but into an object such that I can use the image in a Form it would be awesome :)

Comment: On windows the folder should probably use backslashes `@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\folder\";` . The slide.Name doesn't contain characters that are invalid for NTFS filenames? Is the Presentation file unblocked? (see its file properties)

Comment: @rene i was about to answer my own question with, indeed, your solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You never know nowadays with these write-once, crash everywhere runtimes what a valid path separator is but I'm pretty sure good old COM is picky as hell .... glad you found it.